# The lesser of two evils: Choice between a too long line and a too short line?

Tags: typography, design-principles, typesetting

If I cannot avoid having a line that deviates in length from other lines in a document:
should I choose a slightly shorter line or a slightly longer line?

In this example, the first line of footnote 10 is slightly too long in the first, and slightly too short in the second image.
[image: The first line of footnote 10 is too long]
[image: The first line of footnote 10 is too short]
This problem may occur when writing documents in LaTeX, even after applying the usual measures (e.g. `\emergencystretch`, `\sloppy`).
In LaTeX, you will receive an “underfull \hbox” or “overfull \hbox” warning if this happens.
There may be ways to avoid the problem, but that is not the point and this question is not about LaTeX, it is about typography.
It is not about this particular example either, which is why I added the tag `design-principles`.

Comment: This may be a daft question, but are there hyphens in this language (sorry - I'm going to show my ignorance, in that I haven't got a clue whether the glyphs are Chinese, Japanese or Korean), or, if there are hyphens, are they unacceptable in this context?

Comment: This may also be a daft question, but can you not justify your text?

Comment: You should be asking people who speak this language this question

Comment: There is no such thing as slightly too long etc. I see kerning problems (potentially) if they are not simply double spacing after commas etc. This may be a typeface design issue, or it may be a kerning issue associated with mixed-direction type. Do a search for latex problems associated with mixing right-to-left and left-to-right languages etc

Comment: @Paul This is Chinese and there are no hyphens in Chinese: A multi character word can simply be separated at the end of the line and continued on the next line. The main document language is German, however.

Comment: @ZachSaucier I assume there are numerous people who speak Chinese on Graphic Design SE.
But mainly, I didn’t mean it to be a question about comprehensibility, but about aesthetics.

Comment: @Vinny This is what I use LaTeX for, but it is not meant to typeset CJK. It is now possible to do that, and support is getting better, but LaTeX is still a couple of years (decades) behind concerning CJK.
In LaTeX, instead of justifying text, you define its behaviour when it encounters certain problems. With CJK, some of the regular problems are not handled exactly the same way (and shouldn’t be).

Comment: Could you shorten the length of the two dashes on the line?

Comment: @Yorik Chinese used to be written in columns (top-to-bottom) which were aligned right-to-left, but nowadays it usually isn’t. Instead, it follows left-to-right rows, like in my example. Also, there are no spaces in Chinese. The issue here is that I don’t use a proper Chinese environment in LaTeX, but a very simple self-defined one. This is why LaTeX thinks the whole string of characters (including the non-standard Chinese punctuation is one single word.

Comment: Also, are you likely to hit this problem more than once? Will the solution (ahem! If there is one!) we give here be replicated (as a rule) throughout?

Comment: @Paul The “dashes” (一), are not actually dashes, they are words. Shortening them would be like making one word in an English sentence small.

Comment: @Paul It is very likely that this problem occurs often when people typeset Chinese in LaTeX, but as I said, the question is not how to improve this example text: that would be a LaTeX question and I’d post it in TeX SE.
I meant it to be a general question. If I had to choose: which is considered worse, a slightly long line or a slightly short one? Or: In the above example: which is more acceptable, the long or the short line?

Comment: I realize now that I should have chosen an English example. The reason I didn’t is that LaTeX handles Western languages much better than CJK, and these problems occur less frequently in English :)

Comment: But that makes this an opinion based question, surely?

Comment: @Paul I’m asking for a rule of thumb. If there is no such generally accepted, experience-based view, and all answers would be given in the format “in my opinion, this looks better”, then yes, this would be an opinion based question.
If, however, there is serious advice on this matter, then no, I don’t think it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65492/discussion-between-paul-and-philipp).

Comment: I'm amazed that there is concern over what appears to be ~3mm difference in a *footnote* line length.

Comment: @Scott You are right, of course it doesn’t matter (in 99.9 % of all documents).

Comment: I'm certain, if it's *that* important, you could merely tighten kerning and tracking on the long line in order to condense the spacing to fit. Not ideal, bit if that minute variance in line length is an issue, then perhaps spacing is less imperative.

Comment: @Scott I'm amazed that you would not find a 3 mm difference in footnote line length cause for concern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you admit that this is not about LaTeX, and you wish to have this answer in typographic measurement: there is a slight advantage for a line of text that does NOT end short.

Lines that end short are called "widows" (especially if the line of text is only one or two short words). Reading a document with many widows will take slightly longer to read compared to a document with no widows. The reason is that your eyeball takes extra time to move down, move left, move right, etc etc. Your eyes are like robots: they require a sequence of movements. As a designer, you should minimize the required movement of your reader to complete a task.

There are a more typography tricks that can hinder readability (rags and orphans). If you wish to learn more, here is a good article that introduces these terms:

https://www.fonts.com/content/learning/fontology/level-2/text-typography/rags-widows-orphans